# Unrecognized index variable [i] in R for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I scripted a simple for-loop to iterate over each row of a data set to calculate the distance between two coordinates. The code uses the 'geosphere' package and the 'distm' function which takes two sets of coordinates and returns the distance in meters (which I convert to miles by multiplying by 0.00062137).

Here is my loop:

```
##For loop to find distance in miles for each coordinate pair
miles <- 0
for (i in i:3303) {
miles[i] <- distm(x = c(clean.zips[i,4], clean.zips[i,3]), y = c(clean.zips[i,7], clean.zips[i,6]))[,1] * 0.00062137
}
```

However, when I run it I receive an error:

```
Error: object 'i' not found
```

The thing is, I've run this code before and it worked. Other times, I get this error. I'm not changing any code, it just seems to randomly work only some of the times. I feel the loop must be constructed correctly if it does what I want on occasion, but why would it only work sometimes?

Comment: I can't imagine wanting to actual do `i in i:3303`. Probably it worked once because you have previously defined `i` in your workspace somewhere. But otherwise, it will complain about not knowing what `i` is when resolving `i:3303`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not certain what justifies the down votes on this, but guess I apologize to whomever thought that necessary.

The issue seems to have just been starting the indexing with an actual numeric value like Zheyuan suggested (i.e. using '1:3303' rather than 'i:3303'). I feel like I've created loops before using 'i in i:xxx' without first defining 'i' but maybe not. Anyway, it's solved and thank you!

Comment: What value would that even start with?